# Организация приложений через docker-compose

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Привет!

Осваиваюсь с докером, возникло несколько вопросов. Мне необходимо держать на одной машине зоопарк из приложений на разных технологиях: питон, пхп, нод джс.

Как завести реверс-прокси и пробрасываться в контейнеры я понял, но не могу понять, как организовать следующую инфраструктуру:

app1.example.com:

- node js
- mongo

app2.example.com:

- python
- django
- maria db

app3.example.com:

- php-fpm

---

Хотелось бы заводить каждое из приложений через docker-compose.
Соответственно, вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что перед всеми этими приложениями должен стоять какой-нибудь реверс-прокси, по типу jwilder/nginx-proxy?
2. Если взять готовый nginx-php-fpm-контейнер, например richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/, то получается, что существует 2 нгинкса - один снаружи, другой - внутри? Сейчас у меня это завелось и работает, но хотелось бы собирать контейнеры поотдельности, а не из готовых образов. То есть, отдельно ставить nginx, node js, mongo db. Но как это подружить друг с другом? Был бы очень благодарен за примеры.

Прошу прощения за, возможно, очевидные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно настраивал подобную архитектуру.

Было несколько окружений с набором приложений(несколько docker-compose файлов).  Приложения пробрасывали нужные порты на хост.

Дополнительный docker-compose с граничным nginx'ом(официальный образ), который по доменным именам перенаправлял запросы на хост(доменное имя или ip хоста) и нужный порт( к нужному приложению запрос).

По второй части: получается что может быть несколько nginx. Граничный распределяет запросы по окружения, внутренние могут например отдавать статику для конкретных приложений.

Настойчиво не рекомендуется в один контейнер засовывать больше одного приложения. Потому что контейнер выключается, как только пользовательский процесс заканчивает работать. Да и вообще это не вписывается в идеологию докера.

Answer (score 0):

1) да

2) собираем как нравится. лучше nginx-proxy не обременять php-fpm, а добавить еще один nginx внутрь app3 - так будет безопасней (php еще тот набор дырок) и можно будет гибче рулить nginx конфигами

добавляем в YML еще один сервис nginx-proxy, а для остальных сервисов выставляем опцию **depends_on:** - дабы nginx стартовал первым. если набор приложений динамический, то юзается docker-gen с соответствующим шаблончиком - см. классический пример:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/

этот подход автоматически генерит nginx-proxy конфиг под набор приложений. вот мой слегка причесанный примерчик:

https://github.com/Sfinx/dnleg

так как весьма удобственно сочетать docker-compose с makefile.

Comment: То есть, по сути, в каждом моем аппе должно быть по еще одному нгинксу, который уже непосредственно будет отдавать статику или прокидывать дальше запросы в приложение?

Comment: зачем в каждом ;) ? Только в том где крутятся php скрипты - вообще-то мир уходит от php, так это унылая хрень ;) В идеале имеем только один nginx-proxy который обслуживает все приложения на nodejs. Сквозь этот прокси кстати (через тот же самый порт) прекрасно проходят websockets прямо в nodejs, где с помощью нехитрой логики разделяем HTTP и websocket каналы. И никаких проблем с security, так как достаточно подключить сертификат только к nginx, внутренние сервисы могут работать по открытой docker сети, внешнее web приложение даже знать об этом не будет.